# SharePoint Patching using an admin account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration

I inherited a SP 2013 environment recently in a company which has very strict policies & security measures on everything. I am being told that I will not be provided with the any service account passwords.

I haven't worked in this situation before. My question is it possible to patch the servers or use powershell (by providing my account Add-SPShelladmin access) and do all the admin work without a farm account?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and in fact you should never use service accounts to do any specific task. Make sure your admin account is a Local Admin, Farm Admin, Shell Admin, and has sa in SQL or dbo on all SharePoint databases.

Answer (score 0):

As Trevor said, without Service Account, you can also run SharePoint PowerShell with a farm admin account, you can also create a new farm administrator with PowerShell:

https://piasys.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-farm-administrator-via-powershell/